# Regex to match between two lines

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a regex for a block of string which is dynamic. The dynamic data which I receive has the below format:

```
[Begin] some text goes here.\r\n[Begin] {\r\n[Begin] stage\r\n[Begin] { (dynamicName1)\r\nRandom text here\r\nRandom line2 text\r\nAnd still keeps going\r\n[Begin] }\r\n[Begin] stage\r\n[Begin] { (dynamicName2)\r\nStage dynamicName2 skipped\r\n[Begin] }\r\n
```

Looking to extract the string which is between the pattern as shown below:

```
[Begin] { (dynamicName1)\r\n/*trying to extract this data\r\n//which is available here*/\r\n[Begin] }
```

The pattern I am using is doing half the job but isn't precise in the result. My result also has the **dynamicName1)** line which I need to skip. Trying with these patterns

```
Pattern 1 - /\[Begin\]\s*{\s*\((\w+(?=\))[\S\s]*?)\[Begin\]\s*}/g
Pattern 2 - /\[Begin\]\s*{\s*\(([\S\s]*?)\[Begin\]\s*}/g
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go. I suggest the following pattern:

```
\[Begin\]\s+{\s+\([^()]+\)(.+?)\[Begin\]\s+}
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PbBAOv/2), Sample Code:

```js
const regex = /\[Begin\]\s+{\s+\([^()]+\)(.+?)\[Begin\]\s+}/gm;
const str = `[Begin] some text goes here.\\r\\n[Begin] {\\r\\n[Begin] stage\\r\\n[Begin] { (dynamicName1)\\r\\nRandom text here\\r\\nRandom line2 text\\r\\nAnd still keeps going\\r\\n[Begin] }\\r\\n[Begin] stage\\r\\n[Begin] { (dynamicName2)\\r\\nStage dynamicName2 skipped\\r\\n[Begin] }\\r\\n`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    console.log(`Match: ${m[1]}`);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of a capturing groups and anchors:

```
^\[Begin\]\s+\{\s+\([^()]*\)\s+([\s\S]+?)^\[Begin\][ \t]+}
```

Verbosely:

```
^\[Begin\]            # [Begin] at the beginning of a line
\s+\{\s+\([^()]*\)\s+ # require { and ()
([\s\S]+?)            # capture anything including newlines lazily
^\[Begin\]\s+}        # up to [Begin] }
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/YRjB3s/1/) (and mind the `multiline` mode).

Comment: Appreciate your help but my format of string has got \r\n. Have edited the question.

Comment: @Uzma: Do you have `\r` and `\n` literally? Just change the `\s` then.